# Using array_push with closures overwriting previous element

Tags: php, arrays, callback, closures, array-push

I have a strange problem. I am writing a callback-like system where some code calls a function in a class which adds the function to an array and then later on executes it. Here is my code:

```
class BaconClass {
    private $array;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->array = array();
    }

    public function AddBacon($function) {
        array_push($this->array, $function);
    }

    /* ... */

    public function GetBacon() {
        foreach($this->array as $function) {
            echo $function();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have some other code like this:

```
$bacon = new BaconClass();
$bacon->AddBacon(function() {
    echo "Om nom nom";
});

/* And somewhere else I might have */

$bacon->AddBacon(function() {
    echo "I like bacon";
});

/* And then after all of this I have */
$bacon->GetBacon();
```

This code will only print:

```
I like bacon
```

I have made sure that the array being passed to the `AddBacon` function is actually working, but whenever I use `var_dump` to see what is inside the array after I add an element to it, it always shows one object, which is always the latest one added.

Why is the code overwriting the previous element? If there is a better way to implement this code, I am open to suggestions.

**What I have tried**

I have tried using `$this->array[] = $function`, and I have also tried using `$this->array[count($this->array)] = $function`. Neither are working.

Comment: Show us how you're actually *executing* the code and checking your assumptions. Currently we just see its definition.

Comment: did you try using `$this->array[] = $function`

Comment: @deceze There you go.

Comment: Ok, I just started getting the error `Can't use function return value in write context`. How can I fix this? **Edit** That was actually just a syntax error I just made. I fixed it, but now the whole code is not working...

Comment: You have a function call on the left side of an assignment, e.g. `foo() = bar`. Fix that.

Comment: Are you sure `$bacon` refers to **the same instance**?

Comment: @Barmar I fixed that, now it is back to how it was before.

Comment: @deceze Yes I am sure. I tried `var_dump`ing it on both files and it shows the correct results.

Comment: Well, the code you gave is fine: http://3v4l.org/lZECd

Comment: And BTW, I'd simplify it slightly to this: http://3v4l.org/5PfKS

Comment: Ok, so I am getting a new error now `Argument 1 passed to BaconClass:AddBacon() must be an instance of callable, instance of Closure given`. This is only appearing after I added `callable` to the arguments as @deceze sayed. How would I fix this?

Comment: @mrfishie `callable` type hint may not be applicable to PHP < 5.4. Just skip it. The point is: the code you show is fine. It's time for you to debug the code you don't show.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the provided code in php console, got this output;

```
class BaconClass {
    private $array;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->array = array();
    }

    public function AddBacon($function) {
        array_push($this->array, $function);
    }

    /* ... */

    public function GetBacon() {
        foreach($this->array as $function) {
            echo $function();
        }
    }
}
$bc = new BaconClass();
$bc->AddBacon(function() {echo 'something'; });
$bc->AddBacon(function() {echo 'something else'; });
$bc->GetBacon();
// outputs: somethingsomething else
```

Seems to be working fine to me

Comment: Are there any other methods in the class which are modifying the array?

Comment: Is there any possibility that the code using this class is making new instances instead of reusing the current instance?

Comment: No, I have code that creates the object in one file, then it includes a few files which each do `$bacon->AddBacon()`. Then, I run `$bacon->GetBacon()` back in the original file.

Comment: How are you providing the `$bacon` variable to the other files?

Comment: I am using `$bacon = new BaconClass(); require_once("otherfile.php"); require_once("anotherfile.php") /* maybe some other files here */ $bacon->GetBacon();`

Comment: And you're certain that nowhere in any of those other files do you have something like `$bacon = new BaconClass();`

Comment: Yes I am sure. In fact, on all of the files `$bacon->AddBacon()` is the first line.

Comment: What happens if, immediately after you call `$bacon->AddBacon()` on the first line in each file, you add a `return;` on the second line?

Comment: Not sure, I have changed my code to use a better system that would probably be better, and it appears to be working.